# Regex match string conditions

Tags: regex

Since i'm not so good at regex how can i match some conditions in a string, `StaticString_1number:1number:more than 1number`.

Example:

```
string_3:0:12344555 - Match 
string_s:0:12344555 - No match 
string_3:s:12344555 - No match 
string_3:0:123s4555 - No match
```

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to match exactly?

Comment: Please provide some sample input and the desired output.

Comment: Input - `string_3:0:12344555` - it's ok regex matched  
Input - `string_s:0:12344555` - not ok  
Input - `string_3:s:12344555` - not ok  
Input - `string_3:0:123s4555` - not ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your pattern `StaticString_1number:1number:more than 1number` correctly your regex to match against such strings could look like the following:

```
'^[a-zA-Z]+_[0-9]:[0-9]:[0-9]+$'
```

or if your environment support character classes:

```
'^\w+_\d:\d:\d+$'
```

Answer (score 2):

This Regex would solve your problem:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+_[\d]{1}:[\d]{1}:[\d]+$
```

You can check this link for verification: http://regexr.com?34uj5

Answer (score 1):

This should suit your needs:

```
^[^_]+_\d:\d:\d+$
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?34uiv)

Answer (score 0):

If the initial String can only have characters a-z then the following should work :

```
[a-z A-Z]+_\d:\d:\d+
```

this will match any number of letters up to an underscore then look for single digit before and after colon and multiple digits after second colon.

but you should really have an attempt your self. if in python you could try [re-try](http://re-try.appspot.com/) or in javascript [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) and try out your regex patterns there first.

Answer (score 0):

This may help :   ^[a-zA-Z]*_[0-9]:[0-9]:[0-9]*$